# (REOPENED) How can we get "Is it better to hire someone rather than no one?" reopened?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Is it better to hire someone rather than no one?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97919/is-it-better-to-hire-someone-rather-than-no-one#comment298169_97939)

I tend to think this is a really good question for the site, albeit very difficult to answer meaningfully.

I lean on the side of it being scoped enough for a comprehensive answer and that a good answer could be generalized enough to fit "most" use cases.

But it would also be prone to driveby answers. My worry is if it's scoped too much more it'll end up being industry focused.

Thoughts?

Comment: In some cases it might be, in others its not.  This question is more business than navigating the workplace, and if it wasn't opinion based it would be company dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [substantial edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/97919/3) to change the question from "is X better than Y?" to a less opinion based "what factors to consider when deciding if X or Y is better?" I have trimmed down details from the description accordingly.

I have also cast the 4th reopen vote.

Comment: I cast the 5th and final